# DbContext, EF6 and Automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

In a MVC project, I use Autommaper to link ViewModel and Entities (EF6). I'm looking for an automation, so I'm trying to manage DBContext with Automapper. But, it seem that the Context loose his changes. Do you know why pContext loose changes between the two breakpoints ?

Breakpoint 1: pContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges() = true

Breakpoint 2: pContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges() = false

```
    public void SaveAddress(AddressViewModel pModel)
    {
        OpenTransaction();

        CreateMapAddressModel(Context);
        var lAddress = Mapper.Map<AddressViewModel, Address>(pModel);
        //new DataProvider<Address>(Context).Insert(lAddress);

        CloseTransaction();
    }

    public void CreateMapAddressModel(MyModel pContext)
    {
        if (Mapper.FindTypeMapFor(typeof(AddressViewModel), typeof(Address)).IsNull())
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<AddressViewModel, Address>().IgnoreAllNonExisting()
                .ConstructUsing((AddressViewModel s) => pContext.Set<Address>().Find(s.Id) ?? pContext.Set<Address>().Create())
                .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.ApplicationUser = pContext.Set<ApplicationUser>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == src.ApplicationUserId))
                .AfterMap((src, dest) => pContext.Entry(dest).State = dest.Id == Guid.Empty ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified)
                .AfterMap((src, dest) =>
                {
                    if (dest.Id == Guid.Empty)
                    {
                        //pContext.Set<Address>().Add(dest);
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pContext.Entry(dest).State);//Value = Added
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pContext.ChangeTracker.HasChanges());//Value = True//<-- Breakpoint 1
                    }
                })
                ;
        }
    }//<-- Breakpoint 2
```

Comment: I honestly don't know. But it seems that you are using AutoMapper for what it is not intended, when you are changing the state of the context (pContext.Entry(dest).State =...). I think that only destination's object state should be set when performing mapping.

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Before-and-after-map-actions

"The latter configuration is helpful when you need contextual information fed into before/after map actions." Meaning that AfterMap should be used to provide contextual information, not to change "external" objects.

Comment: I think i found the problem. You're right, I'll stop use Context in Automapper. The context sent to the anonymous function of Automapper  will not be updated because it will be set only when mapping will be created. 
The mapping works well if I add Mapper.Reset(); at the begining. Between Breakpint 1 and 2, pContext is not the same.

Comment: You may want to have a look at this project, it contains details of mapping between view model and entities, in the case it uses ValueInjecter to do that rather than AutoMapper but the implementation might guide you in the right direction http://prodinner.codeplex.com

Comment: Thank for your link. After a month without computer, I'm back on my project. For now, I set the afterMap expression on the Map action and not on the CreateMap action, and it work. I can study this project and find a better approach.